# Python Selenium отрабатывает очень долго

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, phantomjs

Есть следующая страница: https://www.zakon.kz/4935278-nazarbaev-peredal-predsedatelstvo-v.html. И внизу страницы есть блок с комментариями, который подгружается ajax-ом. Пытаюсь получить код страницы через Selenium и PhantomJS. На страницах других сайтов все работает нормально, но на этом сайте, почему то скрипт отрабатывает ну ооочень долго. Доходит до "driver.get" и затем долго думает прежде чем дать ответ. Заметил один интересный момент, что если передать чисто домен сайта https://www.zakon.kz, то все отрабатывает достаточно быстро. В чем может быть причина?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from datetime import datetime
import pymysql

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')

print('1...')
links=[]

#page = "https://www.olx.kz/vko/?page=1"
#page = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/1557037707887249'
page = 'https://tengrinews.kz/money/v-kazahstane-serezno-vyiros-spros-na-dollaryi-352553/'
page = 'https://www.nur.kz/1750800-nazarbaevu-pokazali-kak-proizvodat-elektroavtobusy-v-almaty.html'
page = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4935278-nazarbaev-peredal-predsedatelstvo-v.html'
print('2...')
print(page)
driver.get(page)
print('3...')
for onescroll in  range(0,2):
    print('4...')
    print("scroll"+"_"+str(onescroll))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
print('5...')
htmlfull = driver.page_source
bsfull = BeautifulSoup(htmlfull, 'html.parser')
print('6...')

driver.save_screenshot('1.png')
print('7...')

html = driver.page_source
f = open('1.html','a')
f.write(html)
f.close()
print(html)
```

Comment: Попробуйте, вместо PhantomJS, Chrome или Firefox. Возможно Фантом не понимает где конец загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Решение, должно состоять в быстром получении комментов.

Самая первая мысль, которая приходит в голову -- страница долго отдаётся, потому что долго работает JS. И, действительно. Открываем Chrome (лучше в режиме инкогнито *shift+ctrl+n*), нажимаем *f12* и смотрим, сколько же будет полностью грузиться страница.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине явно видно, что грузилась она секунд 9, не меньше. Вот Вам и ответ. Таким образом, нам нужно поставить таймаут. Как это сделать есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227).

По моим прикидкам, комменты прилетают на 2-3ю секунду (мб раньше), я не замерял (только на глаз). Собственно, ровно тогда Вы их сможете спарсить.

Красивым решением этой проблемы было бы -- вытащить комменты непосредственно сходив на url, с которого они прилетают.

Исследуем код страницы. Перейдём к комментариям и далее -- к блокам, в которых они находятся (в коде):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь мы очень быстро можем найти id комментов, а также найти сайт [zcomments.net](https://zcomments.net), который, судя по всему и хранит все комменты. Напрямую вытащить их не получается. Комменты подгружает [скрипт](https://zcomments.net/js/widget.js?v=20180317), который явно обозначен в коде. Если немного попотеть и отладить его, то можно найти ajax-запрос, который делает обращение к [zcomments.net](https://zcomments.net). Выглядит он так:

```
var ajax = function(params) {
        var data = params.data;
        if (data == null) data = {};
        data._token = _csrfToken;
        $.ajax({
            url: consts.serviceUrl + params.url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'ok') {
                    params.success(data);
                } else {
                    if (params.error != null) params.error(data);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                if (params.error != null) params.error(data);
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        });
    }
```

В нём нас интересуют:

- хост `url: consts.serviceUrl + params.url`. Его значение равно `https://zcomments.net/service/init/1`,
- тип запроса (`type: post`)
- аргументы, которые лежат в `data`. Методом научного тыка, был сделан вывод, что из `data` нужены 3 аргумента: `page_url=https://www.zakon.kz/4935473-perehodit-na-druguyu-vazhnuyu-rabotu.html`, `page_title=Переходит на другую важную работу - министр нацэкономики об уходе Даны Жунусовой`, `block_code=zakonnewsid4935473`.

*Замечание: не забудьте всё заэнкодить*

Таким образом получаем итоговый запрос:

https://zcomments.net/service/init/1?page_title=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83+-+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D0%B1+%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&page_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zakon.kz%2F4935473-perehodit-na-druguyu-vazhnuyu-rabotu.html&block_code=zakonnewsid4935473

Я делал запросы при помощи `Postman`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но можно ходить и curl'ом. Получаем вот такую портянку, в которой можно разглядеть комменты, которые относятся к нужной странице:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "state": "ok",
    "settings": {
        "comments_enabled": true,
        "commenting_enabled": true,
        "premoderation": true,
        "guests": false,
        "smiles": true,
        "pictures": true,
        "youtube": true,
        "formatting": true,
        "period": 0,
        "country_flags": true,
        "comments_mode": "tree",
        "comments_visible": 10,
        "tree_depth": 3,
        "new_widget": false,
        "spam_mode": 0,
        "spam_minutes": 15,
        "spam_messages": 5,
        "interesting_count": 15,
        "interesting_type": 2
    },
    "comments": {
        "total": 1,
        "mode": "tree",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 10522847,
                "block_id": 10339577,
                "company_id": 1,
                "user_id": 114314,
                "user_nick": "Mike Mike",
                "user_source_type": null,
                "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/101343524159214/picture?type=normal",
                "user_country": "kz",
                "message": "Умница! Естественно,свой накопленный опыт,багаж знаний следует передавать своим молодым коллегам!",
                "status": 1,
                "parent_comment_id": null,
                "answer_to_comment_id": null,
                "likes": 0,
                "vote": 0,
                "interesting_comment_id": null,
                "created_hour": 2018090416,
                "created_day": 20180904,
                "created_month": 201809,
                "created_year": 2018,
                "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:16:31",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:22:28",
                "objects": null,
                "created_at_timestamp": 1536077791,
                "likeUsers": [],
                "likePositiveUsers": [],
                "likeNegativeUsers": [],
                "children": [],
                "original": null,
                "answer_to_comment_nickname": null
            }
        ],
        "next_id": null,
        "memory_usage": 3178024,
        "page_size": 10,
        "cached": true,
        "time": 0.00018787384033203125
    },
    "user": null,
    "timestamp": 1536093293,
    "block": {
        "id": 10339577,
        "comments_enabled": true,
        "commenting_enabled": true,
        "premoderate": false
    },
    "socketHost": "https://zcomments.net:3002",
    "token": "D3uXBxHq4ee738fCWf2lAvX3mtrj5swHl0XuW3lH",
    "max_post_size": 1000,
    "max_post_size_warning": 800,
    "lastComments": [
        {
            "id": 10522868,
            "block_id": 10339886,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114416,
            "user_nick": "Strawberry",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": null,
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "А почему только ст. 316 УК РК ему вменяется?!! А угрозы убийством девушке (ст. 115 УК РК), распространение контента, пропагандирующего культ жестокости и насилия, фотографии и видео он же опубликовал в соц. сетях (ст. 313 УК РК), девушку же он оскорблял (ст. 131 УК РК)???",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090419,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 19:02:36",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 19:03:20",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Взорвавший соцсети алматинец заявил, что отрезал головы чучелам и игрушкам",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935584-vzorvavshiy-sotsseti-almatinets-zayavil.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536087756
        },
        {
            "id": 10522867,
            "block_id": 10339721,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 11903,
            "user_nick": "v.i.t.",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": null,
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "это не новость. Есть проще схема- переведите все на гос язык и заставьте поставщика предоставить документы на языке тендерной документации, т.е. на гос. И все.",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090418,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 18:56:57",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 19:03:13",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Чтобы отдать тендер нужной компании чиновники меняют текст с кириллицы на латиницу",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935532-chtoby-otdat-tender-nuzhnoy-kompanii.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536087417
        },
        {
            "id": 10522866,
            "block_id": 10339650,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 107567,
            "user_nick": "Eljas Esengeldiev",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//avatars.yandex.net/get-yapic/0/0-0/islands-200",
            "user_country": "ru",
            "message": "Кидать 50 тенге одно,а 60 млрд долларов просто так другое.И с каких пор отсутствие наивности это пост ленинское сознание?",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": 10522852,
            "answer_to_comment_id": 10522852,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090418,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 18:45:19",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 18:52:52",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Китайский лидер решил вложить в Африку $60 млрд без «политической корысти»",
            "website_url": "https://www.zakon.kz/4935497-kitayskiy-lider-reshil-vlozhit-v-afriku.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536086719
        },
        {
            "id": 10522865,
            "block_id": 10339904,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 100685,
            "user_nick": "Тенгер Великий",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v2.10/202927567122703/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "ru",
            "message": "А на затылке третий глаз можно?",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090418,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 18:37:25",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 18:37:31",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Ученые нашли способ вернуть зрение слепым",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935591-uchenye-nashli-sposob-vernut-zrenie.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536086245
        },
        {
            "id": 10522864,
            "block_id": 10339253,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114299,
            "user_nick": "Abutasneem Adamuly",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/487024658385148/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Что за лицемерство? Почему девочек в платке не пускают школу а насильников пускают потому что среднее образование гарантировано по конституции.",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090418,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 18:02:12",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 18:22:43",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Изнасилованный в селе Абай мальчик и его обидчики пошли в школу",
            "website_url": "https://www.zakon.kz/4935350-iznasilovannyy-v-sele-abay-malchik-i.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536084132
        },
        {
            "id": 10522858,
            "block_id": 10339579,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 104277,
            "user_nick": "Маргарита Никитина",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v2.10/167512304075884/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Министр бы так бдительно за качеством формы следил. Но наехать на родителей проще, чем на предпринимателей.",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090417,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 17:07:07",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 17:08:45",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Cагадиев прокомментировал случай в школе села Фирдаус с ношением платков",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935475-cagadiev-prokommentiroval-sluchay-v.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536080827
        },
        {
            "id": 10522857,
            "block_id": 10339738,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 101218,
            "user_nick": "Адам Базарофф",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//avt-19.foto.mail.ru/mail/ast65/_avatar190?1504856403",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Носит с собой нож. Этим всё сказано...",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": 10522752,
            "answer_to_comment_id": 10522752,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090417,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 17:03:21",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 17:07:07",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Обладатель  Алтын белгі  рассказал, за что убил выпускника школы Актобе",
            "website_url": "https://www.zakon.kz/4935539-obladatel-altyn-belg-rasskazal-za-chto.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536080601
        },
        {
            "id": 10522856,
            "block_id": 10339428,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 24382,
            "user_nick": "АВГУР",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": null,
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Евгений, вы его облили  фактами по самое ,.нехочу,,, оно в ступоре........мое почтение)))",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": 10522837,
            "answer_to_comment_id": 10522837,
            "likes": 3,
            "vote": -1,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:58:07",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 18:24:12",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "В Украине рассказали, когда уведомят Россию о прекращении Договора о дружбе",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935401-v-ukraine-rasskazali-kogda-uvedomyat.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536080287
        },
        {
            "id": 10522855,
            "block_id": 10339558,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 22960,
            "user_nick": "Иван Сергеевич",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": null,
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Такие \"мини клиники\", размером с квартиру, где не будет ни рентгена, ни лабратории (в лучшем случае- электрокардиограф и тонометр) -зачем они нужны? Будет хуже ФАПа. Все равно на самое примитивное обследовпние придется отправлять куда-то. Да и кому из жителей дома понравится, когда у подъезда  в сезон -толпы сопливых и кашляющих людей.",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 1,
            "vote": 1,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:37:28",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:39:35",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Сагинтаев: Нужно размещать поликлиники и детсады на первых этажах новостроек",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935461-sagintaev-nuzhno-razmeshchat.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536079048
        },
        {
            "id": 10522853,
            "block_id": 10339859,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114314,
            "user_nick": "Mike Mike",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/101343524159214/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Уже и в святая святых ничем не брезгуют- то ли ещё...",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:34:31",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:35:17",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Директор Национального центра экспертизы МЗ РК подозревается в крупном хищении",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935579-direktor-natsionalnogo-tsentra.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536078871
        },
        {
            "id": 10522852,
            "block_id": 10339650,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 105495,
            "user_nick": "Казах-PRO .",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": null,
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Я раздаю когда могу. И я  не один такой на свете.<br>Вот видишь, китайцы с меня пример берут :)<br>А тебе надо подрихтовать твое пост-ленинское толи сознание толи подсознание",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": 10522822,
            "answer_to_comment_id": 10522822,
            "likes": 1,
            "vote": 1,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:30:50",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 17:55:17",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Китайский лидер решил вложить в Африку $60 млрд без «политической корысти»",
            "website_url": "https://www.zakon.kz/4935497-kitayskiy-lider-reshil-vlozhit-v-afriku.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536078650
        },
        {
            "id": 10522851,
            "block_id": 10339558,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114314,
            "user_nick": "Mike Mike",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/101343524159214/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Тогда нужно и строить по СНиП и СанПиН - все коммуникации отдельные  от жилых квартир, а не как сейчас все нижние этажи в домах, где по проекту квартиры, заняли под магазины  и пр. муть и результат: грызуны, антисанитария,нет шумо-свето-виброизоляции, в итоге...",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 1,
            "vote": 1,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:29:28",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:39:18",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Сагинтаев: Нужно размещать поликлиники и детсады на первых этажах новостроек",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935461-sagintaev-nuzhno-razmeshchat.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536078568
        },
        {
            "id": 10522848,
            "block_id": 10339133,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 110741,
            "user_nick": "Qanat Boken",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/1235342099935910/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Молодцы акимат Алматы!!!",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:19:59",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:22:30",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "В Алматы заработала скоростная линия BRT",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935298-v-almaty-zarabotala-skorostnaya-liniya.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536077999
        },
        {
            "id": 10522847,
            "block_id": 10339577,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114314,
            "user_nick": "Mike Mike",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/101343524159214/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "Умница! Естественно,свой накопленный опыт,багаж знаний следует передавать своим молодым коллегам!",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:16:31",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:22:28",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Переходит на другую важную работу - министр нацэкономики об уходе Даны Жунусовой",
            "website_url": "https://www.zakon.kz/4935473-perehodit-na-druguyu-vazhnuyu-rabotu.html",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536077791
        },
        {
            "id": 10522846,
            "block_id": 10339813,
            "company_id": 1,
            "user_id": 114411,
            "user_nick": "Аимгуль Максатовна",
            "user_source_type": null,
            "user_avatar": "//graph.facebook.com/v3.0/413797095813854/picture?type=normal",
            "user_country": "kz",
            "message": "в последнее время военные на слуху, новые перемены - к лучшему",
            "status": 1,
            "parent_comment_id": null,
            "answer_to_comment_id": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "vote": 0,
            "interesting_comment_id": null,
            "created_hour": 2018090416,
            "created_day": 20180904,
            "created_month": 201809,
            "created_year": 2018,
            "created_at": "2018-09-04 16:09:32",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-04 16:09:39",
            "objects": null,
            "website_title": "Подразделения Вооруженных Сил повышают боевое мастерство в горной местности",
            "website_url": "http://www.zakon.kz/4935573-podrazdeleniya-vooruzhennyh-sil.html?utm_source=android&utm_medium=news&utm_campaign=mp",
            "created_at_timestamp": 1536077372
        }
    ],
    "funcTime": 0.002664804458618164,
    "startTime": 0.007173061370849609
}
```